# How to store rows of a resultset into HASHMAP

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there any way to store each row of a table contained in a ResultSet into a HashMap ( making each row  an entry to the HashMap).

Comment: Yes you can, but [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Yes there is way to do:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a column form your result set (something that is considered the primary key), and use that for the Map's key property. You can than make your custom class that will hold the rest of the columns as its fields (simple POJO), and use that for the value property. An example:

```
public class MyRow {
    private String col1;
    private int col2;
    ...
    // the constructor
    public MyRow(String s, int i, ...) {
        this.col1 = s;
        this.col2 = i;
        ...
    }
}
```

Assuming you took the int column (if such exist) from your result set to be the map's key, you 'll have something that looks like this:

```
Map<Integer, MyRow> map = new HashMap<Integer, MyRow>(0);
ResultSet rs;
// get your result set from some db query or whatever
while(rs.next()) {
    MyRow mr = new MyRow(rs.getString(yourCol1Index), rs.getInt(yourCol2Index), ...);
    map.put(rs.getInt(yourKeyColumnIndex), mr);
}
// finaly release the resources
rs.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you do it?  Yes.  You write a custom class to represent the data content of a row, then you read the rows, creating an instance for each one and putting it into the HashMap with an appropriate key.

Is there an easier or better way?  Not that I'm aware of.